# Can a Dialogflow API call play audio on my Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I want to create a simple app for use in my house that will cause my Google Home Mini device to speak a custom phrase when executed.  Alternatively to have it play a custom audio file which I will prepare with the phrases.

Ideally I'm looking for something like an API that can be called with a text string that the mini then speaks out.  The API call would come from a web/desktop app I will write.

Can Dialogflow do something like this?  If so, any advice on where to start with the documentation (endpoints etc)?  Or if not, is there anything else out there that I can use to do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @anothermh Appreciated - my applogies.  I have explained the problem above.  I have not tried anything yet as I do not know if the problem can be solved using this tool hence my question

Comment: If you haven't yet tried anything independently then this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow. Give [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a read. Your question should be narrow and specific. Broad questions like this asking if something is even possible and if so what tool should be used end up getting closed. I recommend first doing research on your own, attempt to solve it on your own, and then if you get stuck come back and ask a specific question about where you're stuck. That's what makes a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree.  I have spent a number of days looking for information online and can find nothing conclusive.  I consider SO to be one of the best information sources on the web and have asked questions on here for years.  This is the first time I have had to ask a is this possible question.  Simply saying "read this" and "do research" helps no-one!  Someone has to be the first to ask a question - perhaps the information that explicitly spells out if this is possible is simply not publically, easlily available.  Once this question gets an answer then it will be for the future! Thanks

Comment: You can disagree all you want but it's still off-topic and explicitly not the purpose of stackoverflow. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I really suggest you read the linked articles to understand that I'm not sharing my opinion, I'm sharing with you the very reasons that stackoverflow is -- in your words -- one of the best information sources on the web. (and it's in part because questions like this one get closed and removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) API.

Comment: Thank you.  That has helped and I am now able to proceed with creating something.